# Java Voice Chat Exception : Unsupported PCM_SIGNED

Tags: java, exception, audio

I am making a project in Java. It is through hibernate and JMF. Basically it is project of Audio/Video/Text Chatting. in this, text chatting is running but when I make a audio call to another user, a exception appears.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Line unsupported: interface TargetDataLine s
upporting format PCM_SIGNED 8000.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because of unsupported audio format by system I/O [1](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2221754) [2](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2198477). Query your system for the list of proper formats.

Comment: my files is running in console based chatting.....means I am able to chat b/w 2 systems(one server and one client) through LAN......but getting this exception when using in my project through a common server b/w both(both client) of them......